# I'm seeing occasional build failure due to auto generated files (automake). How do I create dependencies between autogenerated files?

Tags: makefile, dependencies, protocol-buffers, autotools, automake

I have been trying to debug a makefile.am that occasionally causes a build failure in make. In this file, the sources are auto generated .c files and the headers are auto generated .h files.

```
..._SOURCES = @buildDirectory@/x.c
              @buildDirectory@/y.c
              @buildDirectory@/z.c

..._HEADERS = @buildDirectory@/x.h
              @buildDirectory@/y.h
              @buildDirectory@/z.h
```

The failure looks like this

```
<failedproto>.proto: "symbol1" is not defined.
<failedproto>.proto: "symbol2" is not defined.
<failedproto>.proto: "symbol3" is not defined.
...
<failedproto>.proto: warning: Import <failedproto>.proto but not used.
make: *** [<failedproto>.c] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

All of these symbols appear in the a corresponding .h. This leads me to think that the .c is being generated before the .h, and its just a straight race. I have added both ..._SOURCES and _HEADERS to BUILT_SOURCES, but I still see the failure. So my next instinct is to create a dependency for the .c on the .h. How do I do this, since they are both auto generated? Also, any alternative solutions would be welcome too.

Hopefully my formatting is not confusing.

Edit with some more detail:

These files are being auto generated by the protoc-c compiler: https://github.com/protobuf-c/protobuf-c
The protoc-c takes these .proto files and generates .pb-c.c and .pb-c.h files, making me think that these two are not dependent after all. Some in house code is also run, which generates other .proto files, I will call them nameX.proto and nameY.proto, which in turn generate nameX.pb-c.c/nameX.pb-c.h and nameY.pb-c.c/nameY.pb-c.h. A more accurate example of the Makefile.am is like this:

```
..._SOURCES = @buildDirectory@/name.pb-c.c
              @buildDirectory@/nameX.pb-c.c
              @buildDirectory@/nameY.pb-c.c

..._HEADERS = @buildDirectory@/name.pb-c.h
              @buildDirectory@/nameX.pb-c.h
              @buildDirectory@/nameY.pb-c.h
```

I have been trying to track these dependencies, and I will try and describe what conclusions I have come to. nameX.pb-c.c includes its corresponding header nameX.pb-c.h. That header includes nameY.pb-c.h, making me think that nameX.proto is being compiled into nameX.pb-c.c/nameX.pb-c.h before nameY.proto can be compiled. Since there is an include relationship between nameX.pb-c.h and nameY.pb-c.h, the build fails because nameX.pb-c.h needs nameY.pb-c.h. This leads me to two rules I've been suspicious about from the start. These rules are generalized like this:

```
$(OUT_DIRECTORY)/%nameX.proto:$(SRC_DIRECTORY)/name.proto $(SRC_DIRECTORY)/nameY.proto
        command $(OUT_DIRECTORY) $(FLAGS) $<

$(OUT_DIRECTORY)/%nameX.proto:$(SRC_DIRECTORY)/name.proto 
        command $(OUT_DIRECTORY) $(FLAGS) $<
```

Could this be an issue? What is stopping the second rule from being run if it truly needs the first rule?

To make matters worse, many of the .proto files are intermediate files (they are generated then discarded throughout the build) so I cannot look at them to see what they look like.

Comment: It's important to understand that just because a source file (or header file) includes another source file or header file, that **does not** mean that they are prerequisites from make's point of view.  Make only cares about commands that need to be run, the output of the command, and the inputs to the command.  So, for C compilers, the  output is the _object_ file and the inputs are _all the source/headers_,  The sources don't depend on headers, instead the object file depends on the source file AND all its included header files.

Comment: I don't understand why you have two pattern rules with the same target pattern, and where the pattern is not used in the prerequisites list.  Each of these rules says "if you want to build a target that matches `$(OUT_DIRECTORY)/%nameX.proto` you can do it if these prerequisites exist or can be built".  But, if you want to build two targets that both match that pattern, make will run that rule twice... which will presumably generate the same output.  Why do you use a pattern rule here?

Comment: "I don't understand why you have two pattern rules with the same target pattern" - That is an excellent question. I did not write this Makefile, I was saddled with fixing its intermittent build failures. This is my first dive into make so I'm not terribly confident in any of the choices the authors made in this file. When I inherited it is was in terrible shape. As for why we have a pattern rule, it is because there are many more _SOURCE and _HEADERS listed in the Makefile.

Comment: The error message you present does not appear to come from a C compiler.  I'm guessing it must be emitted by protoc-c.  In that case, the issue is probably not with `make` dependencies at all, but rather with your input to protoc-c.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I would agree that this is a protoc-c error. However, the files that are passed to protoc-c are also generated within this Makefile. So I guess its a matter of me tracking down where this daisy chain of auto generation breaks down...

Comment: Fair enough, but the point is that proto-c is *getting* input, and that input seems to be faulty.  This may be because one or more of your rules' recipes is flawed, but I see no reason to think it is related to the values of any Automake variables.  I think the most likely situation, though, is that one of your input files is flawed.

Comment: So you are saying that somehow the files that are being generated are faulty? I hadn't thought of that... I was just trusting protoc-c... One more thing that might be worth consideration, is that this build failure only occurs on a build machine with PARALLEL_MAKE = "-j 32", and almost never on a dev machine, with a lower -J factor (around 16)

Comment: You didn't mention before that the failure was correlated with running parallel make.  That puts everything in a different light.  But my point before was that protoc-c doesn't create anything useful out of thin air.  Somewhere there is at least one input file that you had to write, that informs the whole process.  I was not suggesting that `protoc-c` was malfunctioning, but rather that you might be feeding it bad input.  Directly or indirectly.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not doing a very good job painting a complete picture here am I.. With regards to my initial source files, if it succeeds sometimes, but not all the time, wouldn't it imply that the source is less likely to be a culprit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very unusual to use `@...@` replacements throughout your makefile like this.  Normally you would assign the replacement once, to a make variable, then use the variable instead (in addition to being "nicer to read", this allows someone to override this value on the `make` command line if they want to):

```
BUILDDIR = @buildDirectory@

..._SOURCES = $(BUILDDIR)/x.c
          $(BUILDDIR)/y.c
          $(BUILDDIR)/z.c

..._HEADERS = $(BUILDDIR)/x.h
          $(BUILDDIR)/y.h
          $(BUILDDIR)/z.h
```

Also, it seems likely to me that there are standard automake variables that might already cover this value; if so it's better to use the standard ones than invent new ones... but obviously there's no way to know that without knowing more about your environment.

Anyway, for your question we need to know more about this autogeneration operation.  What do your rules for autogenerating look like now?  Is it really the case that the generation of the .c file can't be done until the .h file is generated?  That's unusual.

If you list the output file, the input files, and the command needed then it's pretty simple to write a correct rule.

Comment: Thanks for showing some interest here, I've updated the question with some more detail.